# Bug with the plane function has_on in cgal?

Tags: c++, cgal

In my program, I have

```
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
typedef K::FT FT;
typedef K::Ray_3 Ray;
typedef K::Line_3 Line;
typedef K::Point_3 Point;
typedef K::Segment_3 Segment;
typedef K::Triangle_3 Triangle;
typedef K::Plane_3 Plane;
#include <QMainWindow>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Point p0(0.103835, -0.0921626, -2.2133);
    Point p1(0.165068, -0.0411001, -2.28194);
    Point p2(0.0954547, -0.0170658, -2.23422);
    Plane plane(p0, p1, p2);
    std::cout << plane.has_on(p0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << plane.has_on(p1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << plane.has_on(p2) << std::endl;
}
```

Then the output is

```
0
1
1
```

but the correct result should be:

```
1
1
1
```

And if I change the Kernel K as

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<float> K
```

Then the result is correct.

And if I change the Kernel K as

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
```

Then output

```
0
0
0
```

So what's the problem? Is there a bug?

Answer (score 0):

As the plane is stored as equation you must use the `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel`.   You only need the `CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel`  if you did orientation tests with 4 points.